# Is there any way to check prop functions and pass it to the next level

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to pass a function down to the container tree. Lets say if I define a function in A, pass it to B and then from B pass it to C. Now I want to do a check in B if I am passing that function, if yes, I pass it down. Is there any way to do it?

Here is the B function:

```
function CategoriesTable({ data, deleteContent }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Table responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th className='text-center'>Count</th>
            <th className='actions'></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((category) => (
            <CategoriesTableRow
              category={category}
              deleteContent={(id) => deleteContent(id)}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now I want to validate whether I am getting a delete function or not? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a function before calling it

```
deleteContent={(id) => deleteContent && deleteContent(id)}
```

or set default param

```
function CategoriesTable({ data, deleteContent = () => null })
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can check it like this

```
function CategoriesTable({ data, deleteContent = () => null  }) {
console.log("Am i getting the function",deleteContent); //to check only by printing it on console
  return (
    <>
      <Table responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th className='text-center'>Count</th>
            <th className='actions'></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((category) => (
            <CategoriesTableRow
              category={category}
              deleteContent={(id) => deleteContent && deleteContent(id)}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
}
```